# Using Distinct() in WriteLine

Tags: c#, linq, csv, duplicates, console-application

I have a console application in C#. I am getting the output

> `System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__81`1[System.Char]`

when I execute my console application.

What I am trying to achieve its to output the projectIds (string) avoiding to output duplicates.

Here you have my code.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outCsvFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    file.WriteLine("ProjectID, ProjectTitle,PublishStatus,NumberOfSubjects,ProjectStartDate,ProjectEndDate,URL");
        for (int s = 0; s < pr.Length; ++s)
        {
            string[] userIDs= new string[] { "" };
                userIDs = db.GetList(pr[s].ProjectID);                
                file.WriteLine("{0},\"{1}\",{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}", pr[s].ProjectID.Distinct(), pr[s].ProjectTitle, pr[s].PublishStatus, userIDs.Length, 
                pr[s].ProjectStartDate,  pr[s].ProjectEndDate,   url[i].ToString());

    }
}
```

Here you have the output and the expected output

[image]

Comment: pr[s].ProjectID.Distinct() returns a generic IEnumerable of type char. I take it you expect a string? You could do new string(pr[s].ProjectID.Distinct().ToArray()) which gives you the string if that is what you are after.

Comment: Please provide a sample input and a sample of the desired output. It is not clear what you want

Comment: I have edited my question to show what I am looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outCsvFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    file.WriteLine("ProjectID, ProjectTitle,PublishStatus,NumberOfSubjects,ProjectStartDate,ProjectEndDate,URL");
    foreach(proj in pr.GroupBy(p=>p.ProjectID).Select(p=>p.First()))
    {
        var userIDs = db.GetList(proj.ProjectID);                
        file.WriteLine("{0},\"{1}\",{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}",
           proj.ProjectID,
           proj.ProjectTitle,
           proj.PublishStatus,
           userIDs.Length.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
           proj.ProjectStartDate.ToString("d",DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
           proj.ProjectEndDate.ToString("d",DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
           url[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

*IF* whatever datatype `pr` is, correctly implements `IEquatable<T>`, you can use distinct easily:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outCsvFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    file.WriteLine("ProjectID, ProjectTitle,PublishStatus,NumberOfSubjects,ProjectStartDate,ProjectEndDate,URL");
    foreach(proj in pr.Distinct())
    {
        var userIDs = db.GetList(proj.ProjectID);                
        file.WriteLine("{0},\"{1}\",{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}",
           proj.ProjectID,
           proj.ProjectTitle,
           proj.PublishStatus,
           userIDs.Length.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
           proj.ProjectStartDate.ToString("d",DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
           proj.ProjectEndDate.ToString("d",DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
           url[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Assuming `pr` is of type `Project`, you can write a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` like this:

```
class ProjectEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Project>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<Project> Members

    public bool Equals(Project x, Project y)
    {
        return x.ProjectID.Equals(y.ProjectID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Project obj)
    {
        return obj.ProjectID.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outCsvFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    file.WriteLine("ProjectID, ProjectTitle,PublishStatus,NumberOfSubjects,ProjectStartDate,ProjectEndDate,URL");
    foreach(proj in pr.Distinct(new ProjectEqualityComparer()))
    {
        var userIDs = db.GetList(proj.ProjectID);                
        file.WriteLine("{0},\"{1}\",{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}",
           proj.ProjectID,
           proj.ProjectTitle,
           proj.PublishStatus,
           userIDs.Length.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
           proj.ProjectStartDate.ToString("d",DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
           proj.ProjectEndDate.ToString("d",DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),               url[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also modified the `userIDs.Length`, and the date fields to use the Invariant Culture so that the file is formatted universally regardless of the user's culture.

Answer (score 1):

`Distinct()` still returns a collection of values, it is just a collection with all the duplicates removed. To generate the string after, you should use something like `string.Join`:

```
string.Join(", ", pr[s].ProjectID.Distinct());
```

This will return the project IDs as a comma separated list.

Comment: You should be using `String.Join` if you want to join a collection of strings.  Not only is this more work, more error prone, harder to understand, etc., but it's *dramatically* less efficient as you're building a large string by concatting strings in a loop.

Comment: @Servy you are totally correct. my brain was just in Linq mode and I didn't even think about it.

Comment: @pquest When I tried it, its spiting the result with the comma separator. I dont want to split the output with the comma separator because the output is suppose to be something line asas22-asdasd1-adasd-4545s

Comment: @Servy How I can add the String.Join with the output? thanks

Comment: `file.WriteLine("{0},\"{1}\",{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}", String.Join(", ",pr[s].ProjectID.Distinct()), pr[s].ProjectTitle, pr[s].PublishStatus, userIDs.Length, pr[s].ProjectStartDate,  pr[s].ProjectEndDate,   url[i].ToString());`

Comment: Hi all, the problem that I am having its that the duplicates has been removed from the output its self on each entry and not on each line. I my csv file what I wanted to do its if I have two identical lines from the project Id I would like to remove one of those lines. Now with the changes its removing the content of each line

Comment: I have edited my question to show what I am looking for, thanks